# How can add a column or cell to row into table when i know exactly position

Tags: jquery, html

I have problem when i try to add column into row of table by i know exactly what rows and column to added

I got index of rows and column therefore i know where my data will adding

Example i have a table with 4 rows and 3 columns

and i want add data into rows 2 cells 3

How can do it with Jquery or Javascript by using 2 loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample http://jsfiddle.net/uwYxU/8/

HTML:

```
<table id="mytable" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>a1</td>
    <td>a2</td>
    <td>a3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b1</td>
    <td>b2</td>
    <td>b3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c1</td>
    <td>c2</td>
    <td>c3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>d1</td>
    <td>d2</td>
    <td>d3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#mytable tr').eq(1).find('td:eq(2)').css({border:'1px solid red'}).text('my data');
```

or

```
$('#mytable tr:eq(1) td:eq(2)').css({border:'1px solid red'}).text('my data');
```

in jQuery eq(0) returns first element, eq(1) second element and so on, it's just like arrays, they start from 0.

**Edit: response to your comment**
you can check if a selector has found anything like this:

```
var selector = $('#mytable tr:eq(1) td:eq(2)');
if(selector.length>0) {
   // Apply styling or other rules
} else {
   // create the missing element and append it
   var missingElement = $('<td>this was missing</td>');
   $('#mytable tr:eq(1)).append(missingElement);
}
```

Comment: if td not exist how can i add it into my row? example row 3 and column 4 not exist ( row 3 just exist column 1 and another one doesnt exist)

Comment: I solved my problem by using for loop to insert cell equals column index of first row

Thank you very much for your reply